# Split the data in text with different patterns

Tags: r, string, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to match a data set with keyword to the text in another data set.

```
S.No    Keyword
1       DKB105A
2       DLB01SA
3       B107A0
4       LB104A0
5       KA02SA
6       A02SA

ID     Date       Text
1   2/11/2020   wrong_B107A0/act
2   2/12/2020   gra/A02SA_fin
3   2/13/2020   Acc/DKB105A/acnt
4   2/14/2020   DLB01SA
5   2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to
6   2/16/2020
```

and the expected output is

```
ID  Date             Text           Keyword
1   2/11/2020   wrong_B107A0/act    B107A0
2   2/12/2020   gra/A02SA_fin       A02SA
3   2/13/2020   Acc/DKB105A/acnt    DKB105A
4   2/14/2020   DLB01SA             DLB01SA
5   2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to      KA02SA
6   2/16/2020
```

Initially, I tried to separate the text like below and then tried to match the keyword.

```
splitdata= setDT(data)[,tstrsplit(Text, '/')]
```

However, I realized later on there are different patters in the text which I cannot split using one patter. Is there a way that I can compare the keywords in the dataset1 with the text in the dataset2.

Comment: What's your rule for handling situations where more than one keyword is present? E.g., in `Text[5]`, both of the last two keywords appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you need:

```r
library(data.table)
keys <- fread('S.No    Keyword
1       DKB105A
2       DLB01SA
3       B107A0
4       LB104A0
5       KA02SA
6       A02SA')

dt <- fread('ID     Date       Text
1   2/11/2020   wrong_B107A0/act
2   2/12/2020   gra/A02SA_fin
3   2/13/2020   Acc/DKB105A/acnt
4   2/14/2020   DLB01SA
5   2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to
6   2/16/2020   _')

keywrds <- paste(keys$Keyword,collapse = '|')
library(stringi)
dt[,Keyword:=unlist(stri_extract_all(Text,regex = keywrds))]
dt
#>    ID      Date             Text Keyword
#> 1:  1 2/11/2020 wrong_B107A0/act  B107A0
#> 2:  2 2/12/2020    gra/A02SA_fin   A02SA
#> 3:  3 2/13/2020 Acc/DKB105A/acnt DKB105A
#> 4:  4 2/14/2020          DLB01SA DLB01SA
#> 5:  5 2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to  KA02SA
#> 6:  6 2/16/2020                _    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works perfectly. However, while working on large data, this is taking lot of time. Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: Using `data.table` is probably your best bet when it comes to speed. But, There's no real way around the regex which is what will consume time. Maybe try @Wimpel's solution with `fuzzyjoin`. It might get faster at scale.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base R with `sapply` as follows:

```
dt$Keyword <- sapply(dt$Text, function(txt) {

    keys$Keyword[sapply(keys$Keyword, function(i) { grepl(i, txt) })]

})
```

Note that this returns a list column where each position in that list is a vector of matching keywords---or, if there are no matches, a vector of length 0. So, if there's more than one keyword in `dt$Text[i]`---as is the case with one of your strings---the list at `dt$Keyword[i]` will include them all. If you know your strings will never include more than one keyword and want to get back a vector column instead of a list column, you could just wrap the whole thing in `unlist()`. So, the result in your case, using the data tables posted in the other answer, is:

```
    > dt
   ID      Date             Text      Keyword
1:  1 2/11/2020 wrong_B107A0/act       B107A0
2:  2 2/12/2020    gra/A02SA_fin        A02SA
3:  3 2/13/2020 Acc/DKB105A/acnt      DKB105A
4:  4 2/14/2020          DLB01SA      DLB01SA
5:  5 2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to KA02SA,A02SA
6:  6 2/16/2020                _
```

Answer (score 1):

`fuzzyjoin`-package solution, using a `regex_join`

It has some (potential) problemens when a text matches multiple Keywoords. You can filter this out later, if desired. Or better, adjust the Keyword-column to actual regexes...

**sample data**

```
library( data.table)
library( fuzzyjoin )

dt1 <- fread('S.No    Keyword
1       DKB105A
2       DLB01SA
3       B107A0
4       LB104A0
5       KA02SA
6       A02SA')

dt2 <- fread('ID     Date       Text
1   2/11/2020   wrong_B107A0/act
2   2/12/2020   gra/A02SA_fin
3   2/13/2020   Acc/DKB105A/acnt
4   2/14/2020   DLB01SA
5   2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to
6   2/16/2020   ""')
```

**code**

```
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join( dt2, dt1, by = c( Text = "Keyword"))
```

**output**

```
#    ID      Date             Text S.No Keyword
# 1:  1 2/11/2020 wrong_B107A0/act    3  B107A0
# 2:  2 2/12/2020    gra/A02SA_fin    6   A02SA
# 3:  3 2/13/2020 Acc/DKB105A/acnt    1 DKB105A
# 4:  4 2/14/2020          DLB01SA    2 DLB01SA
# 5:  5 2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to    5  KA02SA
# 6:  5 2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to    6   A02SA
# 7:  6 2/16/2020                    NA    <NA>
```

## update

with the power of regexes unleashed...

```
fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join( dt2, copy(dt1)[, regex := paste0("[^a-zA-Z]", Keyword, "|^", Keyword)], 
                            by = c( Text = "regex"))[, -"regex"]

#    ID      Date             Text S.No Keyword
# 1:  1 2/11/2020 wrong_B107A0/act    3  B107A0
# 2:  2 2/12/2020    gra/A02SA_fin    6   A02SA
# 3:  3 2/13/2020 Acc/DKB105A/acnt    1 DKB105A
# 4:  4 2/14/2020          DLB01SA    2 DLB01SA
# 5:  5 2/15/2020   KA02SA_attr_to    5  KA02SA
# 6:  6 2/16/2020                    NA    <NA>
```